# How to justify $\bar \psi(x) \psi(x) \bar\psi(y)\psi(y)\Rightarrow -\bar \psi(x) \psi(y) \bar\psi(y)\psi(x)$ in path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, grassmann-numbers

Consider an interaction term of the form $$(e\int dx^4\bar \psi(x) \psi(x))(e\int dy^4 \bar\psi(y)\psi(y))$$ where the generating function was
$$\bar\eta(x)\psi(x)+\bar\psi(x)\eta(x)\Rightarrow \int dx^4dy^4\eta(x)S_F(x-y)\eta(y).$$

In order to get the loop correction the contraction to change from
$$(\bar \psi(x) \psi(x)) (\bar\psi(y)\psi(y))\Rightarrow -(\bar \psi(x) \psi(y))(\bar\psi(y)\psi(x))$$
was needed.

Here's the thing, in the previous expression, if one assign the indices in the matrix form, $$(\bar \psi(x) \psi(x)) (\bar\psi(y)\psi(y))=\sum_{a,b}(\bar \psi^a(x) \psi^a(x)) (\bar\psi^b(y)\psi^b(y)). $$ However, what about $(\bar \psi(x) \psi(y))(\bar\psi(y)\psi(x))$?

In the view of the matrix, this lead to $$\sum_{a,b}(\bar\psi^a(x) \psi^a(y))(\bar\psi^b(y)\psi^b(x))\Rightarrow \sum_{a,b}S_F(x-y)_{aa} S_F(y-x)_{bb},$$ but if one keep the indices to be strict, $$\sum_{a,b}(\bar\psi^a(x) \psi^b(y))(\bar\psi^b(y)\psi^a(x))\Rightarrow \sum_{a,b}S_F(x-y)_{ab} S_F(y-x)_{ba}.$$

Which one was the correct form of the result? i.e. the one which kept track of the indices or the one "conveniently" read off from the matrix.

Comment: Consider $\psi(x)=\frac{\delta}{\delta i\bar \eta(x)}$.

Comment: Did you try with the functional derivatives? It would produce two terms, right? One with the direct contractions and one with cross-contractions.

Comment: Can you add details on your interaction term... it seems weird that it is already integrated over two independent spacetime points...

Comment: They are Grassmannian variables. Exchanging gives a minus sign. In particular, $abc=- cba$

Comment: @ohneVal The interaction term was $e\bar\psi (x) \psi (x) \phi(x)$, but two of those were needed to get the loop diagram and thus $(e\bar\psi (x) \psi (x) \phi(x))(e\bar\psi (y) \psi (y) \phi(y))$ .  The $\phi$ fields were irreverent to the discussion, but they contract with the external legs, and carried the integration of $\int dx^4\int dy^4$.

Comment: @flippiefanus Not sure, googled "direct contractions and cross contractions" didn't find the definition.

Comment: @Prahar It's already done in the title and the pretext.